# error on finish AsyncTask

Tags: android

After recieving a pictures from user, putting them in an array, animate() method  is called from main, this method contains Asynktask. How can I finish this AsyncTask? 
This is my code:

```
    private void animate() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        iv.setImageResource(pics[0]);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            iv.setImageResource(pics[pos]);
                            pos = (pos + 1);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat. Also highlight the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I don't think AsyncTask would be good option for you based on the snippet of code you provided. Try Timer, or just subclass Thread.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I guess what you want is to change the image you show in an ImageView periodically. I'd suggest to change your code to use a [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

```
private Timer mTimer;

private void startCarousel(){
    mTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Your periodic task...
        }
    };

    mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 500);
}

private void stopCarousel(){
    if(mTimer != null){
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();
    }
}
```